# Normal subgroup of direct product of two groups

Tags: group-theory

The following is an exercise from Rotman's book: an introduction to the theory of groups.

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $H\times K$. Show that either $N$ is abelian, or $N\cap H\neq 1$, or $N\cap K\neq 1$.

To prove it, we may assume that $H, K$ are the images of two projections of $N$ respectively. If $N\cap H = N\cap K\ = 1$, by Goursat's lemma, we know that $N\cong H\times_{G}K$, where $G = H\cong K$. But how can we show that $N$ is abelian in this case?
I don't know what is the use of the normality of $N$ here. Could anybody help me?

Comment: Consider the commutator $[(h,1),n]$ for $n \in N$.

Comment: Hint: You can actually show that if $N$ intersects trivially with both $H$ and $K$ then $N$ is central (and thus abelian). To do this, you just need to show that everything in $N$ commutes with everything in $H$ and with everything in $K$. To do this, compute a commutator between such elements and use the normality of the subgroups.

Comment: Thanks very much. How silly I am. Actually N, H, K are all normal!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** If $A$ and $B$ are normal subgroups of a group $G$ and $A \cap B = 1$, then $ab = ba$ for each $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.

Comment: Yes. Of course. Thanks.